# Custom content in Cross-reference?

Tags: ms-word, cross-reference

I use MS Word to write requirements, to keep the format and numbering of each, I use soft-return (SHIFT/RETURN) as the following image
[Easy to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e5rFp.png)

and then start the next automated tag by a regular RETURN.

I try to make proper use of Word's "Cross-reference" and usually insert with "Paragraph number (full context)"
[Insert Cross-reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYRQl.png)

to get
[normal Cross-reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R27md.png)

which then contain only get the "Numbered item" text i.e. "SampleTag_x".

I could use option "Paragraph text" but will then get the full content
"<requirement 1>
It shall be nice to read a requirement.
**Rational**: Everyone benefit from a consequent formatting."

What I would like to get is only the first line: "SampleTag_1 <requirement 1>"
[Numbered item + first line of paragraph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UI7RD.png)

As of now, I hard code the name of the requirement after the acctual Cross-reference, which works fine since it usually stays the same, the important stuff is to get the auto-numbering item to update if moved or subject to insertations above etc.

But I wonder, is there a way to do extract paragraph content with a search like "everything up until the first SOFT/RETURN character" etc? I could accept having to enter two seperate Cross-references after each other, as long as they are for the same target (but with different field coding).

Comment: If you use a style for the requirement paragraph (use a normal return then) and another style for the description paragraph this should work. You can then use "Style for following paragraph": for the requirements-style chose the description style and vice versa.

Comment: This is not a programming question and, as such, is off-topic for Stack Overflow. Questions on general usage of Microsoft Word should be asked on an appropriate end-use forum (e.g., MS Answers).